# Performance benefit of adding function to $scope?

Tags: javascript, performance, angularjs, scope

Is there a major performance benefit to adding a function to $scope that doesn't need to be on $scope?

example:

```
function myCtrl($scope){
    $scope.myFunc = function(){
        // my function on scope
        var four = myHelperFunc(2);
        return four;
    }

    function myHelperFunc(number){
        // my helper function
        return number * 2;
    }
}
```

versus:

```
function myCtrl($scope){
    $scope.myFunc = function(){
        // my function on scope
        var four = $scope.myHelperFunc(2);
        return four;
    }

    $scope.myHelperFunc = function(number){
        // my helper function on scope
        // is this better than the previous example?
        return number * 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt the performance will be more than minuscule. You're just giving the scope another variable to watch out for. Could be useful later on if you need to extend your application to watch out for that particular scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is better, it will use lexical scoping. The second will use object state memory on the heap. As the number of objects grows, you'll consume more memory just to keep the reference `$scope.myHelperFunc`.

All in all, I'd recommend to not worry about this, it's better to write clean code that expresses what you are doing. Performance difference is really minimal in this example and it depends on the actual vendor's JS engine implementation on the client side, which you can't really control. Unless... it's server side code.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer @pid, my main concern is when you changed controllers within an angular application the current scope gets destroyed, but would the functions not on scope still be taking up memory?

Comment: This depends on the JS engine. I can imagine that Google's V8 (used in Chromium, thus the *Chrome* browser) keeps the compiled function in memory as long as possible, and this is a good thing. Small handlers as these take up hundreds of bytes (maybe thousands, but not really much more). So, on a low-level smartphone with say, 128 MB RAM (which is not much, today) it is a tiny drop in the ocean. Performance wise, V8 will save a lot of CPU time having kept those bytes in memory.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a performance benefit to the latter. In the end, a function is still called. The difference is whether you want your helper function to be able to be called from the UI. On the $scope you can code a call to it, inside the controller you control access and only call it from your functions. It's more an API visibility concern than a performance one.